# Pass Apex action as parameter in LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

Is it possible to pass Apex action as a parameter to other LWC component? This code gives me error

> [LWC component's @wire target property or method threw an error during value provisioning. Original error:
> [g$LWS[7] is not a function]]

Is there any way to achieve this?

**mainComponent.js**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import apexMethod from '@salesforce/apex/ApexClass.apexMethod';
import { doSomeLogic } from 'c/commonFeatures';

export default class DisplayMatchingBCRs extends LightningElement {

   @api recordId;

   @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: [FIELDS] })
       wiredRecord({ error, data }) {
           if (data) {
               doSomeLogic({callback: apexMethod})
           }
    }
}
```

**commonFeatures.js**

```
const doSomeLogic = ({callback}) => {
    callback()
        .then(result => {
            console.log(result)
        });
}

export { doSomeLogic };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not in the manner you're trying to do. What ends up happening is that the runtime complains about not having a VM (note: partly because `this` is set to the wrong object). The best you can do is handle the result, something like:

```
export const doSomeLogic = (...result) => {
  console.log(result);
}
```

Which you call as:

```
apexMethod().then(doSomeLogic);
```

However, you could also use the mixin design:

```
const Utils = (superclass) => class extends superclass {
  doSomeLogic({callback}) {
    callback().then(result=>{console.log(result);});
  }
};
export default Utils;
```

Which you can then use in any other class:

```
import Utils from 'c/utils';
import apexMethod from '@salesforce/apex/MyClass.MyMethod';

export default class MyComponent extends Utils(LightningElement) {
  someMethod() {
    this.doSomeLogic({callback:apexMethod});
  }
}
```

Comment: sfdcfox, this is completely new to me. I am not able to find Mixin design implementation anywhere on salesforce document. Can you help me with that ?

Comment: @AnshulAgrawal You won't find mixins directly in the documentation (but note that [lightning-navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation) includes the NavigationMixin). You'll want to read a basic tutorial to learn more, such as [this one](https://javascript.info/mixins).

Comment: The mixin approach is what I needed, thanks!